# How do I show that $E(X)$ exists?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ is a random variable that is bounded which is $P\{|X| \le M\} = 1 $ and $0 < M < \infty$ then show that $E(X)$ exists.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{S},P)$ be a probability space.

I know that $E(X)$ for a random variable exists if $E(|X|)$ exists ,i.e., $\sum_k|x_k|p_k$ exists.

Now $P\{|X| \le M \} = 1$ means that the random variable $|X|(\omega) \le M, \forall \omega \in \mathcal{S}$.

Then we see that $E(|X|) = \sum_k |x_k|p_k \le M \sum_kp_k = M$ and $M < \infty$ . Hence $E(|X|)$ exists. Is this proof correct?

Also if $X$ is a random variable then $|X|$ is also a random variable?

Comment: It is not correct because you are not told that $X$ is a discrete random variable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I agree with you that the OP didn't prove it in general. However, is the OP's proof valid for the discrete case?

Comment: I am not sure does it seem wrong for the discrete case too?

Comment: $|X|(\omega)|\leq M$ for all $ \omega \in \mathcal S$ does not make sense.

Comment: $P\{|X| \le M\} = 1$ and $P(\Omega) = 1$ so I thought the random variable $|X|$ can only assume values between $[0,M]$ that is why I wrote $|X|(\omega) \le M$ for all $\omega \in \mathcal{S}$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $X \in \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ (i.e. $E[X]$ exists and is $\mathbb{R}$-valued) iff $E[|X|]<\infty$. We have that
$$E[|X|]=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|\leq M\}}|X|]+\underbrace{E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>M\}}|X|]}_{=0}\leq M<\infty$$
This is because $\{|X|>M\}$ is a $P$-null set. To see this, consider the usual argument to prove that if $A$ is $P$-null and $Y$ a random variable, then $E[\mathbf{1}_A|Y|]=0$:
$$E[\mathbf{1}_A|Y|]=E\bigg[\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbf{1}_A(|Y|\wedge n)\bigg]\stackrel{\textrm{MCT}}{=}\lim_{n \to \infty}E[\mathbf{1}_A(|Y|\wedge n)]\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}n P(A)=0$$